# Alterar as cores da tabela zebrada bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, table

Estou usando o bootstrap e uma tabela com

> table-striped

e ta ficando um zebrado bem clarinho,como altero as cores do zebrado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo css sobrescreva a classe **table-stripes**:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Altere a cor conforme desejar alterado o **red** pela cor desejada..

Comment: deu certo,obrigado.